# return a value immediately from collection by java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8

Consider a list of int[](in array).

Now I want to check the last element of the integer array be equal to 10. If any of the elments in the array is equal to 10 
then I want to return true immediately.
Else I want to return false.

This is my method to achieve this.

```
boolean checkList(List<int[]> attrList, Parent parent)  {


    for (int[] list : attrList)
    {
        if(parent.isAttributeEqualsTo10(list[list.length-1]))
              return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Now How will I achieve this using Java 8 streams since we are iterating a collection.

Comment: This one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/java-8-find-first-element-by-predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `anyMatch` :

```
return !attrList.stream().anyMatch (l -> parent.isAttributeEqualsTo10(l[l.length-1]));
```

Comment: Isn’t `! … anyMatch(…)` the same as `… `[`noneMatch(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)?