# How do I return objects with lambdas java

Tags: java, lambda

Say I have a List addressees, and the properties for the address are
1. ID
2. Name
3. State
Then I have a get method to get an address by ID

```
public Address get(Integer id) {
    for (Address myAddress : addresses) {
        if (myAddress.getId() == id) {
            return myAddress;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is how it would look without lambdas
How do I return the address using lambdas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/java-8-find-first-element-by-predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should according to your context something like:

```
// Find any address that matches
addresses.stream().filter(a -> a.getId() == id).findAny();
```

or

```
// Find the first address that matches
addresses.stream().filter(a -> a.getId() == id).findFirst();
```

The first approach is mostly interesting in case you want to parallelize the search using `addresses.parallelStream().filter(a -> a.getId() == id).findAny()`, it will be much faster than the second approach as it will stop seeking as soon as we have a result. The second approach is more interesting in case you don't intend to parallelize it which seems to be your case here.

So finally, it gives:

```
public Address get(Integer id) {
    return addresses.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getId() == id)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Er, why wouldn't you write `return result.orElse(null)`?

Comment: Thankyou :) I was missing the findFirst at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this:

```
public Address get(Integer id) {
    return addresses.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getId().equals(id))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: ahhh I see, I was missing the findFirst() at the end. Also in your filter it should be getId() == id ;) but it works. thanks!

Comment: Do you mean your Address object contains an id field of type int but your method signature is Integer id ?

Comment: yeah sorry, I should of clarified that better.