# Best way to traverse and find an object field from a list

Tags: java, list, equals

I have a list of Custom object and i want to find an object by given an Id(a field in custom object). i was coding for this so i found two solutions when comparing fields.

1

```
private Product getProduct(String productId,List<Product> productList){
        for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
            if (productId.equals(productList.get(i).getId())) {
                return productList.get(i);
            }


        }
        return null;
    }
```

2.

```
 private Product getProduct(String productId,List<Product> productList){
        for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
            if (productList.get(i).getId().equals(productId)) {
                return productList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The difference is in `if` condition , i want to know which one is better than the other and why, when to use 1st method and when to use second  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `equals()` is [required](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) by Java to be *symmetric*, there is no difference between the two snippets.

Both snippets are sub-optimal, in that they iterate by numeric index, and retrieve `productList.get(i)` twice before returning it. Iterating by index is especially dangerous, because passing a `LinkedList<Product>` will slow down your search considerably.

A better approach is to use a for-each form of the loop:

```
for (Product p : productList) {
    if (p.getId().equals(productId)) {
        return p;
    }
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

The concern in both of your implementations is the possibility of calling .equals on a null value.

If you can guarantee neither of them are null then they are equivalent.

If you are using Java 8, stream may be a better choice.

```
private Product getProduct(String productId,List<Product> productList){
    return products.stream()
        .filter(p-> productId.equals(p.getId())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one invokes `equals` on the parameter `productId`, while the second one invokes `equals` on the current list element from `productList`. The result is the same because [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is *symmetric*:

> for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.

You can also use a stream for this, so you don't have to care about implementation details (furthermore, [`Objects#equals(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) is null-safe):

```
String p = productList.stream().filter(e -> Objects.equals(e, productId))
                               .findFirst()
                               .orElse(null);
```

Have a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23696317/3429133) question for further information.

Comment: i know the result is some but i think equals has some thing which depends on how it is used

Comment: @AdnanAli Don't worry, `equals` is defined as `x.equals(y) = y.equals(x)`, so order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure the product id's are never null it doesn't really matter.

But in general it's always good to program in a defensive way, so for example prefer using

```
"SomeString".equals(aString)
```

instead of

```
aString.equals("SomeString")
```

since you know "SomeString" is never `null`.

Or use

```
Objects.equals(object1, object2)
```

when both objects might be `null`.