# Multiple if statements having incorrect output

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I want to fill the `acts` array with values of some enum. While iterating I want to input commands from console, but my if statements don't find any match and I always get the output `"Incorrect"`.

My code:

```
Action[] acts = new Action[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter act: ");
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in1.next();
    acts[i] = new Action();
    if (s.equals("rotate_forw")) 
        acts[i].type = ActionType.RotF;
    if (s.equals("rotate_back")) 
        acts[i].type = ActionType.RotB;
    if (s.equals("shift_forw")) 
        acts[i].type = ActionType.ShiftF;
    if (s.equals("shift_back")) 
        acts[i].type = ActionType.ShiftB;
    else 
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: You described what you want, but not what problem you are facing. Do you get any error/exception/incorrect result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `else` clause applies only to the last `if` statement, so you get the `"Incorrect"` output whenever `s.equals("shift_back")` is `false`.

Your statements should be replaced with a single if-else-if...-else statement, so that `"Incorrect"` is only printed if **all** the conditions are `false` :

```
Action[] acts = new Action[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (s.equals("rotate_forw"))
        acts[i].type = ActionType.RotF;
    else if (s.equals("rotate_back"))
        acts[i].type = ActionType.RotB;
    else if (s.equals("shift_forw"))
        acts[i].type = ActionType.ShiftF;
    else if (s.equals("shift_back"))
        acts[i].type = ActionType.ShiftB;
    else
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
}
```

You should also consider what you want to assign to `acts[i].type` when the input is incorrect. Perhaps you should throw an exception in this case.

Answer (score 1):

While @Eran's answer is correct, I'd like to suggest a different approach that encapsulates the enum with the translation from the external coding.  Consider this:

```
public class EnumDemo
{
    public static enum ActionType
    {
        Incorrect(""),
        RotF("rotate_forw"),
        RotB("rotate_back"),
        ShiftF("shift_forw"),
        ShiftB("shift_back");

        private String code;
        private ActionType(String code)
        {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public static ActionType fromString(String code)
        {
            return Arrays.stream(ActionType.values())
                         .filter(v->v.code.equals(code))  
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(ActionType.Incorrect);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] testData = {  
            "rotate_forw", 
            "rotate_back", 
            "shift_forw", 
            "shift_back", 
            "junk", 
            null };

        Arrays.stream(testData)
              .forEach(t->System.out.printf("\"%s\" -> ActionType.%s\n", t, ActionType.fromString(t)));
    }
}
```

This uses the fact that enum constants can have associated data. I've added an instance variable `code` to hold the external encoding of each enum value. Then I added a static `fromString(String code)` method to the enum that looks up the provided code in the list of values. For 4 possibilities a simple linear search, equivalent to your `if-then-else` cascade, works fine.  If there were dozens or more I'd set up a `Map<String,ActionType>` to handle the conversion.

The search using streams bears some explanation.

1. First create a `Stream` of enum values
2. Filter it to contain only enum values whose `code` matches the desired code (there should be only one)
3. Pick off the first entry, which comes back in a `Optional`.  If nothing was found (i.e. the code is invalid) the `Optional` will be empty.
4. Use the `orElse` method to return the value if it exists or `ActionType.Incorrect` if not.

At first glance this might look inefficient since one expects that the `filter()` predicate has to scan the entire stream even if the desired element occurs early.  This is a really nifty feature of Streams -- all intermediate streams are "lazy", so the filter won't iterate over the entire list if it finds the desired entry early.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23696317/18157) for details.

Output:

```
"rotate_forw" -> ActionType.RotF
"rotate_back" -> ActionType.RotB
"shift_forw" -> ActionType.ShiftF
"shift_back" -> ActionType.ShiftB
"junk" -> ActionType.Incorrect
"null" -> ActionType.Incorrect
```

The last testcase shows the code is null-safe.

The biggest advantage is that the mapping is in the same place as the enum itself, so you won't have to hunt for the code when you add or remove an enum value.  Also you can't forget to define the mapping since it's required by the enum's constructor.