# Get index of element that matches a predicate

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I know how to find the first element of a list by predicate:
[Find first element by predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/java-8-find-first-element-by-predicate)

Is there an easy way to get the index of that element?

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/java-8-find-first-element-by-predicate. Although answers to that question can be used to construct an answer to this one, there could also be answers which don't require iterating the stream.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understood correctly, that's the classic case where you need `IntStream`; but that would only apply for a List obviously.

```
IntStream.range(0, yourList.size())
   .filter(i -> yourList.get(i)... your filter condition)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If you really only want the first index, use `findFirst()` instead of `collect(...)`. This will only execute the filter until you find the first match.