# Java with ArrayLists the index of function

Tags: java

is there a way with the index of function to return the index of a value that is part of a class like just one field of the bigger structure.. I got a simple contact class and I want to return the index when the id is a certain value .. should I be using a different structure than an arrayList it is doing most of what I want but the index of function is frustrating

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<yourList.size();++i) {if(yourFilterHere) {return i;}}`?

Comment: Maybe you could use a Map rather than a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to just iterate over the array, and check the condition with "if". That will be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Predicate method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605707/get-index-of-element-that-matches-a-predicate).

```
Optional<Integer> indexOfMatch = IntStream.range(0, yourList.size())
   .filter(i -> valueYouAreLookingFor.equals(yourList.get(i).getFieldYouAreChecking()))
   .findFirst();
```

Or if the field holds a primitive value:

```
Optional<Integer> indexOfMatch = IntStream.range(0, yourList.size())
   .filter(i -> valueYouAreLookingFor == yourList.get(i).getFieldYouAreChecking())
   .findFirst();
```

If there is an element in the list that matches your predicate, `indexOfMatch` will have the index of that element. If not, `indexOfMatch` will be an empty `Optional`.

Regarding whether an ArrayList is the appropriate structure, generally if you are working with a list of values, an implementation of `List` is what you want. Whether it should be `ArrayList` or some other implementation depends on details of what you are doing with the list. For small list sizes, it often doesn't really matter which implementation you use.

Comment: Append `.orElse(-1)` to `findFirst()` and you'll get `-1` if not found, just like `List.indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

I am iterating over the ArrayList and seeing whether the current value is the id value you want.

```
int yourValue = 25; //I am assuming it to be an int of value 25, you can keep it whatever you want. 

for (int i = 0; i < yourArrayList.size(); i++)
{
    if (yourArrayList.get(i) == yourValue)
    {
        return i; //returning the index value
    }
}

return null; //this will run if the value doesn't exist.
```

Obviously, this would need to be inside a method that returns an integer that is the index. Above, `yourArrayList` is the ArrayList you are using, and `yourValue` is the value you need to find. It doesn't have to be an int.

Answer (score 0):

well I switched to a vector from an array list but it did not really help but I did use a loop and the list size and just put the contact in a container each time so I could do my comparison it was kinda messy but I got the index that way.

```
static int SearchForContact(String ContactID) {
    int temp = -1;
    Contact searchCon;
        for (int z = 0 ; z < contactVector.size(); z++)
        {searchCon = contactVector.get(z);
        if(searchCon.getId() == ContactID)
            {temp = z;}
        }
        if (temp == -1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Contact not found");
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Lol this is almost the same as my answer other than you used a vector. Cool though!