# Java Streams return a specific class

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list which contains many token requestors but ID is unique and *filter* will returns **just one** object.

```
for (TokenRequestor requestor : tokenRequestorList) {
    if (requestor.getId().equals(tokenRequestor.getId())) {
        System.out.println("This object is unique!");
    }
}
```

I try write this code in Java 8:

```
tokenRequestorList.stream().filter(tr -> tr.getId()
        .equals(tokenRequestor.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How I can filter to return a **TokenRequestor**? This list will be contain 1 element.

E.g:

```
TokenRequestor myObject = tokenRequestorList.stream()
        .filter(tr -> tr.getId().equals(tokenRequestor.getId()))....;
```

Comment: [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) !?

Comment: What if there isn't even one?

Comment: I'd use findFirst(...) instead of filter(...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 find first element by predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/java-8-find-first-element-by-predicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tokenRequestorList.stream()
    .filter(tr -> tr.getId().equals(tokenRequestor.getId()))
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

This will return any `TokenRequestor` instance matching the filter (in your case it will be unique), or `null` is nothing matches the filter.