# How to achieve the same result as with filter and findFirst

Tags: java

Is there a more elegant way to achieve by using java 8 or above the eighth version what's below?

```
 List<String> exampleList = List.of("test","test1");
 exampleList.stream().filter(s -> s.equals("test")).findFirst();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it the elegant version?

Comment: What bothers you about the solution you already have?

Comment: You're using streams, which were added in Java 8...

Comment: It's okay for me, but I just thouth that perhaps that can be achieved just by using one function. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you want to do.

If you just want to check if `"test"` is in one of the elements, you could just use `.contains()`:

```
List.of("test","test1").contains("test");
```

If you want to find the first element fitting a condition, you can omit creating the list and directly create a `Stream`:

```
Stream.of("test","test1").filter(s->"test".equals(s)).findFirst()
```

If you want to check if an element fitting the condition exist, you can use anyMatch:

```
Stream.of("test","test1").anyMatch(s->"test".equals(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best your going to get.

```
List<String> exampleList = List.of("test","test1");
exampleList.stream().filter("test"::equals).findFirst();
```

If its reused you can just make a method out of the 2nd line. Question has also already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/find-first-element-by-predicate)