# Convert for loop with a return statement to stream and filter lambda statement

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert the below for loop with return statement to a lambda expression or stream with filter.

```
for(PhysicianData d : physicianDataList)
    {
        if(d.getPhysicianName().equals(physicianName))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's also [Find first element by predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/find-first-element-by-predicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
boolean result = physicianDataList.stream()
            .map(PhysicianData::getPhysicianName) // Stream of names
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) //Skip nulls
            .anyMatch(name -> name.equals(physicianName));
```

Comment: This one's even cleaner, cauz it's one step at a time

Comment: Hi, is anyMatch a null safe method because I am getting NPE when getPhysicianName method returns a null

Comment: Iam trying using a filter in between. Will post here after tests are complete

Comment: `filter(Objects::notNull)` would work

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for **anything** that matches the name equality check (anything being the operative word), I suggest having a look at the [`Stream::anyMatch()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-anymatch-java-examples/) method, as well as its other counterparts of [`Stream::allMatch()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-allmatch-java-examples/) and [`Stream::noneMatch()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-nonematch-method-java-examples/). The above code can be rewritten as:

```java
boolean result = physicianDataList
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(physicianData -> physicianData.getPhysicianName().equals(physicianName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it:

```
    class PhysicianData {
    String physicianName;

    public void setPhysicianName(final String physicianName) {
        this.physicianName = physicianName;
    }

    public String getPhysicianName() {
        return physicianName;
    }
}

@Test
void test() {
    PhysicianData one = new PhysicianData();
    one.setPhysicianName("A");
    PhysicianData two = new PhysicianData();
    two.setPhysicianName("B");
    List<PhysicianData> physicianDataList = List.of(one, two);
    assertEquals(forMethod("A", physicianDataList), streamMethode("A", physicianDataList));
}

private boolean forMethod(final String physicianName, final List<PhysicianData> physicianDataList) {
    for (PhysicianData d : physicianDataList) {
        if (d.getPhysicianName().equals(physicianName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean streamMethode(final String physicianName, final List<PhysicianData> physicianDataList) {
    return physicianDataList.stream().anyMatch(x-> x.getPhysicianName().equals(physicianName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `anyMatch()` that takes a predicate as an argument

```java
boolean isFound = physicianDataList.stream()
             .anyMatch(d -> d.getPhysicianName().equals(physicianName));
```

Comment: While this works, its easier to read with a `map` in between imho