# How to make findAll stop on first predicate

Tags: java, groovy

I've got a question if I'm somehow able to make this code working like this:

If it matches the first predicate: `(it.controller == controllerName && it.actions.contains(actionName))`, it finds only those, which match this predicate and it doesn't find from those underneath.

If it doesn't find anything from first predicate, then it goes to second one and finds all which match second predicate, but don't match the third one.

```java
 ArrayList rule = rules.findAll {
            (it.controller == controllerName && it.actions.contains(actionName)) 
            ||
            (it.controller == controllerName && it.actions.contains("*")) 
            ||
            (it.controller == "*" && it.actions.contains("*"))
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understood the question correctly, this should work:

```
def filterFirst(List list, List<Closure> filters) {
        return filters
                .collect { list.findAll(it) }
                .find { it.size() != 0 }
}
```

Then, just do

```
filterFirst(rules, [
        { it.controller == controllerName && it.actions.contains(actionName) },
        { it.controller == controllerName && it.actions.contains("*") },
        { it.controller == "*" && it.actions.contains("*") }
])
```

Comment: `.collect` is going to visit every element in `filters`.  Would it be better to use something like `find` to find the first one that matches and then jump ship so the rest don't have to be visited?

Answer (score 0):

Use `findFirst()` instead, here's are some good references: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-findfirst-vs-findany and [Find first element by predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/find-first-element-by-predicate)

Comment: Groovy's version of findFirst() is called find: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)