# searching through specific attributes of an arraylist of objects

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of objects `ArrayList<Tile> list` Tile has attributes of `new Tile("colour", value)` I want to make a search function where I iterate though each `Colour` attribute of the Tile and each `Value` attribute within each colour in the arraylist (like a nested for each loop), is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: How is Tile class defined? please share the code.

Comment: @NamrataShukla added

Comment: Have you looked into Java 8 streams? You can use filtering for example: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940416/fetch-first-element-which-matches-criteria if you want to search for the first match.

Comment: Can you tell a simple _example data_ of what the search function input and output might be? You can add it to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Tile` class has two attributes a `String` `colour` and an `int` `value`. It has a `toString` (`java.lang.Object class`'s override method) like this:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return colour + ":" + value;
}
```

Make some tiles:

```
Tile t1 = new Tile("red", 7); // constructor takes a colour and a value
Tile t2 = new Tile("red", 2);
Tile t3 = new Tile("blue", 9);
Tile t4 = new Tile("white", 17);
Tile t5 = new Tile("blue", 3);
Tile t6 = new Tile("red", 15);
Tile t7 = new Tile("white", 10);
```

**Scenario 1:**

The function takes a list of `Tile` objects and a `String` colour as input and returns all tiles with the input colour (and their values). There are two ways to do that and these are shown in two methods:

```
private static List<Tile> getTilesWithColor1(List<Tile> tilesList, String searchColor) {
    return tilesList.stream()
                     .filter(tile -> tile.getColour().equals(searchColor))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static List<Tile> getTilesWithColor2(List<Tile> tilesList, String searchColor) {
    List<Tile> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Tile t : tilesList) {
        if (t.getColour().equals(searchColor)) {
            result.add(t);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

- The input: `tilesList`, `colour="red"`
- The output (from both methods is same): `[red:7, red:2, red:15]`

> I want to make a search function where I iterate though each Colour
>   attribute of the Tile and each Value attribute within each colour in
>   the arraylist (like a nested for each loop), is there an easy way of
>   doing this?

One can alter this function to add additional conditions or filters to get required result.

**Scenario 2:**

Get all colors and their values:

```
private static Map<String, List<Integer>> getTileColorsAndValues(List<Tile> tilesList) {
    return tilesList.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tile::getColour,
                         Collectors.mapping(Tile::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

- The input: `tilesList`
- The output: `{red=[7, 2, 15], white=[17, 10], blue=[9, 3]}`

Note one can get the values within the "red" tiles like this from the resulting map:

```
List<Integer> valuesList = map.get("red");
```

**Scenario 3:**

Get all tiles by color:

```
private static Map<String, List<Tile>> getTilesByColorsAndValues(List<Tile> tilesList) {
    return tilesList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tile::getColour));
}
```

- The input: `tilesList`
- The output: `{red=[red:7, red:2, red:15], white=[white:17, white:10], blue=[blue:9, blue:3]}`

Note one can get the tiles within the "red" tiles like this from the resulting map:

```
List<Tile> tilesList = map.get("red");
```

---

**The Example's Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class TilesExample {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Tile t1 = new Tile("red", 7);
        Tile t2 = new Tile("red", 2);
        Tile t3 = new Tile("blue", 9);
        Tile t4 = new Tile("white", 17);
        Tile t5 = new Tile("blue", 3);
        Tile t6 = new Tile("red", 15);
        Tile t7 = new Tile("white", 10);
        List<Tile> tilesList = Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7);

        System.out.println(getTilesWithColor1(tilesList, "red"));
        System.out.println(getTilesWithColor2(tilesList, "red"));

        System.out.println(getTileColorsAndValues(tilesList));

        System.out.println(getTilesByColorsAndValues(tilesList));
    }

    private static Map<String, List<Tile>> getTilesByColorsAndValues(List<Tile> tilesList) {
        return tilesList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tile::getColour));
    }

    private static Map<String, List<Integer>> getTileColorsAndValues(List<Tile> tilesList) {
        return tilesList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tile::getColour,
                            Collectors.mapping(Tile::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
    }

    private static List<Tile> getTilesWithColor1(List<Tile> tilesList, String searchColor) {
        return tilesList.stream()
                         .filter(tile -> tile.getColour().equals(searchColor))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<Tile> getTilesWithColor2(List<Tile> tilesList, String searchColor) {
        List<Tile> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Tile t : tilesList) {
            if (t.getColour().equals(searchColor)) {
                result.add(t);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this was very helpful. I really appreciate it

Comment: Did it answer your question? If so, which aspect of it?

Comment: all 3 solutions were helpful, solution 3 in particular helped me with the main search issue, and the other 2 solutions helped me with other problems I was having trouble with