# Translate for loop with condition by streaming and filtering

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to translate `getFromTestStatus` method to do exactly the same but using Stream and filtering if necessary

```
public enum TestStatus {
  CANCELLED("Cancelled"),
  IN_PROGRESS("In Progress"),
  TO_VALIDATE("To Validate"),
  VALIDATED("Validated"),
  EXPIRED("Expired");

  private final String id;

  public static TestStatus getFromTestStatus(String status) {
    for (TestStatus testStatus : TestStatus.values()) {
      if (testStatus.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
        return testStatus;
      }
    }
    
    return null;
  }
}
```

I'm learning to use streams so I have no idea on how to achieve this. So far I've done the following:

```
public static TestStatus getFromTestStatus(String status) {
  return Stream.of(TestStatus.values())
      .map(TestStatus::getId)
      .filter(id -> {
        return id.equalsIgnoreCase(status);
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Obviously I get a List of Strings, but I can't figure out how to reduce it to just one element (that list has not more than one element) and get null if no element is found.

Also I'm getting `String` and I should return the corresponding TestStatus, not its `id`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940416/fetch-first-element-which-matches-criteria

You are very close to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey i would do this as followes

```
public static Optional<TestStatus> getFromTestStatus(String status) {
  return Stream.of(TestStatus.values())
      .filter(id -> id.equalsIgnoreCase(status)) // you don't need the brackets here.
      .findFirst() //This returns an optional so you don't need to return null
      .orElse(null) //Do this if you force the stream to return null if not found
}
```

Comment: This is good! But I need to return the corresponding `TestStatus`, not its `id`...

Comment: The you should not map the TestStatus to the correspondig ID. You only should use the id in the filter.
filter(teststatus -> testStatus.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(status))
And ignore the map statement then. ;)

Comment: Yep, found out just now haha. Thank you man! Appreciate it

Comment: Just a little tip. Enums have a static .valueOf method wich give you the correspondig enum by name.
I. e. TestStatus.valueOf("TO_VALIDATE") returns the TO_VALIDATE Type. Maybe thats useful. ;)

Comment: It definitely is. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

A working solution complying with method `TestStatus::getFromTestStatus` is as follows:

1. Implement missing private constructor and (optionally) public getter of `id` field in `TestStatus`
2. Fix issues in `getFromTestStatus` method:

```java
public enum TestStatus {
    CANCELLED("Cancelled"),
    IN_PROGRESS("In Progress"),
    TO_VALIDATE("To Validate"),
    VALIDATED("Validated"),
    EXPIRED("Expired");

    private final String id;
  
    private TestStatus(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
  
    public String getId() { return id; }

    public static TestStatus getFromTestStatus(String status) {
        return Arrays.stream(TestStatus.values())  // Stream.of calls Arrays.stream
            .filter(st -> st.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(status)) // compare id field to status
            .findFirst()   // returns Optional<TestStatus>
            .orElse(null); // fix missing ';', return null if no status is found 
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(TestStatus.getFromTestStatus("cancelled"));
System.out.println(TestStatus.getFromTestStatus("canceled"));
```

Output:

```
CANCELLED
null
```